# How to install PostGis on EC2 micro-instance

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, amazon-ec2

I tried to install PostGIS on my Amazon EC2 microinstance using `sudo yum install postgis2` and got following error message:

```
$ sudo yum install postgis2                        
Loaded plugins: priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates                                             | 2.3 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package postgis2 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can I install PostGIS on an EC2 microinstance?

Comment: The question is 650mb enough enough to run postgis? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html

Comment: @Mapperz Good point. AFAIK there is an EC2-compatible hosting provider Digital Ocean, which offers 2 GB RAM, which should be sufficient for simple experiments. https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most simple option is switching to some other distro, they don't limit your choice by just Fedora, even for micro instances. https://aws.amazon.com/amis/ - Try Ubuntu, or OpenSuse

OpenSuse postgis2 package: http://software.opensuse.org/package/postgis2
Ubuntu PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise

Also you can build PostGIS from source: http://postgis.net/source, that's a manageable task too, that's what I normally do on Ubuntu 12.04